# Kudu Console SSH vs Bash (Python(3.x) package installation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

What is the difference when I install python packages using `SSH` or `Bash`. I cannot see the packages in `Bash`(pip list) which I installed using `SSH`.

Answer (score 0):

The bash console coincides with KuduLite and the SSH console is related to the container your app is running in.

> Therefore, if you need to get Docker logs or other logs, always use the Kudu Bash console instead of using SSH to access your app's container. (See this for more information on how to get the latest Docker logs from Kudu.)

[Reference](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/ba-p/392472)